# Backbone not to add a route to history

Tags: backbone.js

I have a route I want to be able to navigate in series. 
Unfortunately Backbone doesn't make it possible to navigate the same route twice.

Is it possible not to save this route to the history?

I have this route:

```
app_router.on('route:deleteFile', function(filename){
        var r=confirm("Do you really want to delete "+filename);
        if (r==true)
          {
           //delete instruction
          }
    });
```

If I don't accept the confirm by mistake, I can't choose the same file to delete again.
Because the route is already reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution consist of navigating to the previous route when you don't accept the confirm, without triggering it :

```
app_router.on('route:deleteFile', function(filename){
    var r=confirm("Do you really want to delete "+filename);
    if (r==true)
      {
       //delete instruction
      }
    else
      {
        Backbone.history.navigate(/* previous rout */, {trigger: false});
      }
});
```

Comment: Do I have to set the previous route as comment, or do I have to enter the previous route as route as I would navigate to it by router.navitage("PreviousRoute") ?

Comment: I mentioned the PreviousRoute root as an example, you can put any root that differ from the current `route:deleteFile` and yes you enter the route as you would navigate to it by router.navitage("PreviousRoute").

Comment: It works. I can put any route in it. Due to trigger:false it's not doing anything :)